# Travis-CI urls point to my fork

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am integrating travis-ci and I need to include the url to the build status points to my fork.

If I create a PR, they will have to change README.md and redirect that.

```
[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/FORK_USER/PROJECT.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/FORK_USER/PROJECT)
```

How do I replace FORK_USER with something that works once the PR is merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Github markdown simply does not have any placeholder functionality for repos, users, etc. It's been a [feature request](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/913) for a long time too.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue